# I want to send a value to hidden element from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here is my code in JavaScript  and I want to create innerhtml button that will fill some hidden fields in my html form and I have problem maybe with the quotes, when I try to fill the AirportsForm.kod variable...

```
function EditTableCell(a)
{
    var Myp= document.getElementById(a);
    var nam=Myp.textContent;
    var kod=Myp.id;
    alert(kod);
    var newHTML='<p id="'+a+'"><input size="35" type="text" name="edit'+a+'" id="edit'+a+'" value="'+nam+'" /><input type="button" value="Change" onclick="document.AirportsForm.kod.value='+"'a'"+'.value;document.AirportsForm.promena.value=document.AirportsForm.edit'+a+'.value;document.AirportsForm.submit();"/></p>';
}
```

here is the html: Its in the form AirportsForm

```
<input type="hidden" name="promena" id="promena" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="kod" id="kod" value="" />
```

And in Php, I do `$variable=$_POST["kod"]` and for other hidden element.

Comment: There's no clear question, no description of problem you've encountered. Just "I want..."

Comment: @Tony: This question isn't properly formatted.

Comment: Show us the HTML and skip the irrelevant code that nobody can understand anyway.

Comment: What error do you get, what do you expect, why do you think you have a problem with quotes, could you make a jsfiddle for it, what is your goal, etc

Comment: the error is here 
onclick="document.AirportsForm.kod.value='+"'a'"+'.value;
how to write it corectly because as u can se it has signle quotes for <input type=button and then doublequotes for on click...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i finished it for you and this way works, because u get an htmlObject element or input element here you should do it object.id or value or whatever u want to get and than use it later...

function EditTableCell(a)
{

```
var Myp= document.getElementById(a);
var nam=Myp.textContent;
var newHTML='<p id="'+a+'"><input size="35" type="text" name="edit'+a+'" id="edit'+a+'" value="'+nam+'" /><input id="'+a+'" type="button" value="Change" onclick="document.AirportsForm.promena.value=document.AirportsForm.edit'+a+'.value;return subb(this);"/></p>';
Myp.innerHTML = newHTML;
Myp.onclick=null;
}
function subb(b)
 {
  document.AirportsForm.kod.value=b.id; 
    document.AirportsForm.submit();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

make it a little cleaner... call a function inside `onclick` and do your step there

```
var newHTML='<p id="'+a+'"><input size="35" type="text" name="edit'+a+'" id="edit'+a+'" value="'+nam+'" /><input type="button" value="Change" onclick="someFunction(\''+ a +'\')"/></p>';

function someFunction(a){
  document.AirportsForm.kod.value=a.value;
  document.AirportsForm.promena.value=document.AirportsForm.edita.value;
  document.AirportsForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: when i try to send the a it says that a is ObjectHTMLCollection but it should be string...

Comment: try `alert(a)` in side `EditTableCell` function and check what u get there ...

Comment: there i get the correct string that i need

Comment: i am just passing the string to the `someFunction(a)` here..so this should work.... i think `a.value` is doing something here... make sure if that is what u need..

Answer (score 0):

you can use getAttribute() function for change an attribute value as:

```
var kod=Myp.getAttribute('id');
```

FOR MORE READ CLICK [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp)